# Align exponent and number below each other

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I´m trying to align the exponent with a normal number below each other using align. However I´m not able to use the & in the exponent to tell where it should be aligned.

The desired output should look like this:

[image: desired output]

My current solution looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
f(x)=P(X=x) &= \begin{cases}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e&^{-\lambda},\quad x \in \ 
{0, 1, \dots\}\\ &0,\quad \text{sonst} \end{cases} \label{eq:poisson}
\end{align}
```

and results in:

[image: current output]

I know that I would need to place the & sign before the lambda but as soon as I try it, the code doesn´t compile correct anymore. Is there any way to use the & command in the exponent?

Many thanks

Comment: The desired output is made by an `array` environment and `\left{ \right.`. However, it is not really good, especially in spacing. There are some more environments which can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt about my preference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x)=P(X=x)=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e&^{-\lambda} && x\in\{0,1,\dotsc\} \\
&0 && \text{sonst}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(x)=P(X=x)=
\begin{dcases}
\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda} & x\in\{0,1,\dotsc\} \\
0 & \text{sonst}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The latter, of course.

By the way, don't use `align` for single equations.

Comment: missing the ,'s though, although this should be very minor in Terms of effort in tex although the expressions above now strictly mathmatically make no sense for exactly that reason

Comment: `sonst=const` into the code of OP:-)? Is it true? :-) But I have not understood if the 2nd image is made with word office (font Cambria Math).

Comment: @Sebastiano *Sonst* means *otherwise* in German.

Comment: @egreg That was a bad figure I made. I didn't know that at all. Excuse me.

Comment: @egreg Do you know how i can add the `,` directly after the results? I´ve tried adding them and aligning at them but it results in a huge whitespace between the e-function and the `,`.
So in conclusion the commas should follow directly after the equations and should be directly below each other.

Comment: @MaximilianSpeicher I usually don't add commas after the term; if I had to, I'd place them next to the object, just like normally.